# Printing Prime numbers in a range

Tags: c, loops, nested-loops, primes

My code is not running the loop. I've tried changing it from `for` to `while` loop, tried changing the condition for prime number but still the same response. I've attached my output in this [program output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMHiR.png) image.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void) {

  int a, b, flag = 0;
  int i, j;

  printf("Enter lower limit of range\n");
  scanf("%d", &a);

  printf("Enter upper limit of range\n");
  scanf("%d", &b);

  printf("The prime numbers between %d and %d are\n", a, b);

  i = a;
  j = 2;

  while (i <= b) {

    while ( j < i/2 )
    {
        if (i % j == 0)
        {
            flag = 1;
        } 
        j++; 
    }
    if (flag == 0)
    {
        printf("%d\n", i);
    }
    i++;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you reset the flag to zero with each new `i`?

Comment: Oh, and not testing the return value from scanf (it should be 1) is always asking for trouble.

Comment: BTW the image link shows a totally different program. What's up?

Comment: Besides `flag` it seems that `j` also needs to be reinitialized for each `i`

Comment: Instead of the nested loops, write a function `int is_prime(int n)` that you can call in a simple loop... much easier

Comment: sorry for the wrong image and my professor has asked me not to use functions, he wants me to use loops and if else only.  I'll try reinitializing ```flag``` and ```j``` thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

You need at least to reset the variable `flag` to `0` and `j` to `2` in each iteration of the outer loop. Also the condition `j < i /2` should be changed to `j <= i / 2` (for example when `i` is equal to `4`).

```
  while (i <= b) {

    flag = 0;
    j = 2;
    while ( flag == 0 && j <= i/2 )
    {
        if (i % j == 0)
        {
            flag = 1;
        } 
        j++; 
    }
    if (flag == 0)
    {
        printf("%d\n", i);
    }
    i++;
  }
```

Pay attention to that the program can incorrectly consider 2 as a non-prime number and 1 as a prime number.

I would write the loops the following way

```
for ( ; i <= b; i++ ) 
{
    int prime = i % 2 == 0 ? i == 2 : ( i == 3 ) || ( i != 1 && i % 3 != 0 );
    for ( int j = 5; prime && j <= i / j; j += 6 )
    {
        prime = i % j != 0 && i % ( j + 2 ) != 0;
    }

    if ( prime )
    {
        printf("%d\n", i);
    }
}
```

Or a more simple variant

```
for ( ; i <= b; i++ ) 
{
    int prime = i % 2 == 0 ? i == 2 : i != 1;
    for ( int j = 3; prime && j <= i / j; j += 2 )
    {
        prime = i % j != 0;
    }

    if ( prime )
    {
        printf("%d\n", i);
    }
}
```

You should declare the variables `a` and `b` as having the type `unsigned int` instead of `int` to avoid using negative numbers.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    unsigned int a = 0, b = 0;

    printf( "Enter lower limit of range " );
    scanf( "%u", &a );

    printf( "Enter upper limit of range " );
    scanf( "%u", &b );

    printf( "The prime numbers between %u and %u are\n", a, b );

    for ( unsigned int i = a; i <= b; i++ )
    {
        int prime = i % 2 == 0 ? i == 2 : i != 1;
        for ( unsigned int j = 3; prime && j <= i / j; j += 2 )
        {
            prime = i % j != 0;
        }

        if (prime)
        {
            printf( "%u ", i );
        }
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter lower limit of range 0
Enter upper limit of range 100
The prime numbers between 0 and 100 are
2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97
```